# JAVA input.nextLine(); not stopping for input

Tags: java

I have started work on a program to keep track of scores for my buddies and I when we play darts. Unfortunately when I enter the number of players and the method asks for player names, it skips over the input for player 1. I used input.nextLine() since I need to be able to record first and last names in one string at times. It works just fine for each subsequent player, but bypasses player 1 by default.
The code is as follows:

```
if (playerCount >= 1)
{
    System.out.println("Enter name for Player 1: ");
    name1 = input.nextLine();
}

if (playerCount >= 2)
{
    System.out.println("Enter name for Player 2: ");
    name2 = input.nextLine();
}

if (playerCount >= 3)
{
    System.out.println("Enter name for Player 3: ");
    name3 = input.nextLine();
}

if (playerCount >= 4)
{
    System.out.println("Enter name for Player 4: ");
    name4 = input.nextLine();
}

if (playerCount >= 5)
{
    System.out.println("Enter name for Player 5: ");
    name5 = input.nextLine();
}

if (playerCount >= 6)
{
    System.out.println("Enter name for Player 6: ");
    name6 = input.nextLine();
}

if (playerCount >= 7)
{
    System.out.println("Enter name for Player 7: ");
    name7 = input.nextLine();
}

if (playerCount >= 8)
{
    System.out.println("Enter name for Player 8: ");
    name8 = input.nextLine();
}
```

Once I type, for example, 4 players, I get this:

> Enter number of players:  4
>   Enter name for Player 1:
>
> Enter name for Player 2: Johnny Bravo
>
> Enter name for Player 3: Kevin Bacon
>
> Enter name for Player 4: Kyle
>
> Players: 4
>
> [this space is blank]
>
> Johnny Bravo
>
> Kevin Bacon
>
> Kyle

Please let me know why it is doing this, as well as why replacing the player1 if contents with the following works, despite the code redundancy:

```
if (playerCount >= 1)
{
    System.out.println("Enter name for Player 1: ");
    name1 = input.nextLine();
    name1 = input.nextLine();
}
```

Comment: You probably call `nextInt()` before you call `nextLine();` The first method does not consume the new line character from the console so when the 2nd method executes it just grabs the new line alone.

Comment: Suggestion: use a loop and a string array rather than named variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Live demo: https://repl.it/repls/LimitedGlitteringComments

The reason why is `.nextInt()` just gets the next integer, not the newline or anything. So the next time you say `.nextLine()` it gets nothing but a `\n`. That's why after the `.nextInt()` I did `input.nextLine();`

Also I eliminated your big `if`, by putting in a for loop.

Hope this helped!

```
int numberOfPlayers;
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter number of players:");
numberOfPlayers = input.nextInt();
input.nextLine();
String[] arrayOfPlayers = new String[numberOfPlayers];
for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfPlayers; i++) {
  System.out.println("Enter name for Player " + i + ":");
  arrayOfPlayers[i-1] = input.nextLine();
}
// print list
for (String player : arrayOfPlayers) {
    System.out.println(player);
}

input.close();
```

Comment: I just don't have much experience yet, so bare with me. If I understand correctly, you are first solving my main issue with the 'input.nextLine()' after the 'nextInt()', then declaring a String array for the player names with a number of indexes based on the playerCount variable, populating it with names with the first for-loop, then displaying the names with another for-loop. I imagine I could create an int array for the scores for each player. How would I go about creating a struct? I want to have dart1,2,3/round. I figure I could do the main score with: for(round) > for(player) > for(dart#)

Comment: Please make a new question for that, and I'll be happy to help you there :) If this answer helped remember to upvote and mark as the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

Get your player count using the below code.

```
int playerCount = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
```

nextInt() doesn't consume the newline character that you give after taking playerCount input. It gets consumed in the next nextLine() call.